# How to merge each two elements of the lists into list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have two lists:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Is there any way to get this list out of these?

```
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

Comment: `list(zip(a,b))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` to interleave lists and form list of tuples:

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(list(zip(lst1, lst2)))
# [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```